# MIPS Assembly: Calculating the byte offset of array element with two variables

Tags: assembly, mips

How would I do line 7?

I was thinking add $t3, $t0, $t1 but there is a subtraction before the byte offset of element 'x'

[image: byte-copy.jpg]

[image: byte.jpg]

Comment: Can you think of a way to subtract?  Here's an [instruction set summary](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61c/resources/MIPS_Green_Sheet.pdf).

Comment: What does `sll ...,2` do?  It multiplies by 4, which can be used to make a byte offset from a regular index, but you can also multiply by 4, or add together twice -- all equivalent except that `sll` is the most efficient approach.  We need a byte offset because the machine is byte addressable, so each word takes 4 bytes and correspondingly, 4 byte addresses.  So, the next word is 4 byte addresses further along.

Comment: For `B[i+x]` we need `B + (i+x)*4`.  However, because multiplication distributes over addition, we can rewrite that as `B + i*4 + x*4`, which is one way of computing it.  So, for the byte offset part, you can shift `i` by 2 & shift `x` by 2 then add them together, or the other way: add `i+x` together, then shift that -- both work to make a byte offset.

Comment: so it would be sub $t3, $t0, $t1

Comment: Yes, that will work: that is using the shift first approach.  However, I think they might be looking for the shift last approach, since it mentions "in a different way".

Comment: As people commented on your first post of this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72504321/mips-assembly-calculating-the-byte-offset-of-array-element-with-two-variables), don't post images of text.  Especially faint hard-to-read ones.  If you want people to look at code, at least type the parts that are necessary to understand the question.  (You could still include an image for context.)